How can I make it so that every 50 emails sent wait 60 seconds to send the next 50?
I have this class in Ruby on Rails:
class DeliverInviteEmailJob < ApplicationJob

  queue_as :default

  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) do
    retry_until_limit_reached
  end

  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) do |exception|
    retry_until_limit_reached_and_log(retry_limit: 0, exception: exception)
  end

  def perform(invite_id)
    invite = Invite.find(invite_id)

    #I think i can introduce my code from here

    Email.create_from_invite!(invite)
  end
end

I am using Sidekiq and Redis.
In a single batch there could be 4000 emails to be sent.
ChatGPT suggests me this code but I have doubts, since I have one Sidekiq for both production and Staging I want to proceed with caution
  def update_job_counter
    
    counter = Redis.current.get('deliver_invite_email_job_counter').to_i

    if (counter + 1) % 50 == 0
      
      Redis.current.set('deliver_invite_email_job_counter', 0)

      sleep(120)
    else
      Redis.current.incr('deliver_invite_email_job_counter')
    end
  end

Does Active job create counters for the created jobs?
Could making a job wait cause queuing problems?
